# considering purchasing JxBrowser .... any cheaper or FOSS alternatives?

Tags: java

I just bought it with my student loan.

Comment: You haven't told us much of the requirements.

Comment: @bmargulies - the prime requirement is that it costs less ... :-)

Comment: But what do you need it to DO? Does it have to be Java? Does it have to be a full browser? If your professor writes a nice note to teamdev would they give you a student deal?

Comment: If you need it for an open source project development, they will provide a free license.

Answer (score 2):

As I know TeamDev Ltd. provides "Free Licences for Education Purposes": http://www.teamdev.com/company/specialprograms/#studentsProgram

If you are a student then I think you could use it.